# How to use ArrayList for such implementation ? or If HashMap is good for it then how to use it for such implementation?

Tags: android, android-layout, arraylist, hashmap, android-listview

Right now i am using the ArrayList for My ListView and there is a Custom ListView in My Application.

See the Image Below:
[image]

Now i am using this code to display the list and set the value to the listView:

```
    public void getOrders(){
        try{
//              if(employer)
//              {
                    System.out.println("You are in Employer");
                    m_orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
                    payListForEmployer = new String[] {"Tax Code","Pay period Begin","Pay Frequency","Salary/Wage per pay",
                            "Net or Gross Amount","KiwiSaver Member","Employee Deduction","Employee Contributions",
                            "Complying Fund Member","Fund Contribution","ESCT Tax Rate","Child Support Deduction","Payroll giving donation"};

                    Order o[]=new Order[payListForEmployer.length];
                    System.out.println("The Length of payListEmployer is: "+payListForEmployer.length);

                    for (int i = 0; i < payListForEmployer.length; i++) 
                    {
                        o[i]=new Order();
                        o[i].setOrderName(payListForEmployer[i]);

                        // for TAXCODE
                        if(i==0) {
                            taxCodeValue = PAYEEmployerDetail.taxCodeFinalValue;
                            if((taxCodeValue==null)) {
                                taxCodeValue = "Please select";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(taxCodeValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());

                        }
                        // for Pay Period Begin
                        if(i==1) {
                            //payPeriodValue = myPrefs.getString("payperiod", "12 09 2011");
                            payPeriodValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.payPeriodFinalValue;
                            if((payPeriodValue==null)) {
                                payPeriodValue = "--/--/----";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payPeriodValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for Pay frequency
                        if(i==2) {
                            //payFrequencyValue = myPrefs.getString("payfrequency", "Weekly");
                            payFrequencyValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.payFrequencyFinalValue;
                            if((payFrequencyValue==null)) {
                                payFrequencyValue = "Please select";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payFrequencyValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for salary / wage
                        if(i==3) {
                            salaryWageValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.salaryWageFinalValue;
                            if((salaryWageValue==null)||(salaryWageValue.equals(""))) {
                                salaryWageValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                salaryWageValue = "$"+salaryWageValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(salaryWageValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // For Gross / Net
                        if(i==4) {

                            o[i].setOrderStatus("Gross");
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }

                        // for KiwiSaver Member 
                        if(i==5){
                            kiwiSaverMemberValue = PAYEEmployerDetail.kiwiSaverMemberFinalValue;
                            if((kiwiSaverMemberValue==null)||(kiwiSaverMemberValue.equals(""))){
                                kiwiSaverMemberValue = "No";
                            }else{
                                kiwiSaverMemberValue = PAYEEmployerDetail.kiwiSaverMemberFinalValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(kiwiSaverMemberValue);
                        }

                        // for KS Employee Deduction    
                        if(i==6) {
                            employeeDeductionValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.employeeDeductionFinalValue;
                            if((employeeDeductionValue==null)||(employeeDeductionValue.equals(""))) {
                                employeeDeductionValue = "0%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(employeeDeductionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        // for KS Employee Contribution
                        if(i==7) {
                            employeeContributionValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.employeeContributionFinalValue;
                            if((employeeContributionValue==null)||(employeeContributionValue.equals(""))) {
                                employeeContributionValue = "0%";
                            }
                            else{
                                employeeContributionValue = employeeContributionValue+"%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(employeeContributionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }

                        // for Complying Fund Member
                        if(i==8){
                            complyingFundMemberValue = PAYEEmployerDetail.complyingFundMemberFinalValue;
                            if((complyingFundMemberValue==null)||(complyingFundMemberValue.equals(""))){
                                complyingFundMemberValue = "No";
                            }else{
                                complyingFundMemberValue = PAYEEmployerDetail.complyingFundMemberFinalValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(complyingFundMemberValue);
                        }
                        // for Fund Contribution
                        if(i==9){
                            fundContributionValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.fundContributionFinalValue;
                            if((fundContributionValue==null)||(fundContributionValue.equals(""))) {
                                fundContributionValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                fundContributionValue = "$"+fundContributionValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(fundContributionValue);

                        }
                        // for ESCT Tax Rate
                        if(i==10){
                            ESCTTaxRateValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.ESCTTaxRateFinalValue;
                            if((ESCTTaxRateValue==null)||(ESCTTaxRateValue.equals(""))) {
                                ESCTTaxRateValue = "0%";
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(ESCTTaxRateValue);
                        }
                        // for Child Support Deduction
                        if(i==11) {
                            childSupportDeductionValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.childSupportDeductionFinalValue;
                            if((childSupportDeductionValue==null)||(childSupportDeductionValue.equals(""))) {
                                childSupportDeductionValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                childSupportDeductionValue = "$"+childSupportDeductionValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(childSupportDeductionValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }

                        // for Payroll giving donation
                        if(i==12) {
                            payrollDonationValue =  PAYEEmployerDetail.payrollDonationFinalValue;
                            if((payrollDonationValue==null)||(payrollDonationValue.equals(""))) {
                                payrollDonationValue = "$0";
                            }
                            else{
                                payrollDonationValue = "$"+payrollDonationValue;
                            }
                            o[i].setOrderStatus(payrollDonationValue);
                            //System.out.println("The Value is: "+o[i].getOrderStatus());
                        }
                        m_orders.add(o[i]);
                        //lv.invalidate();
//                      System.out.println("==> TaXCode Value: "+PAYEEmployerDetail.taxCodeFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> PAyPeriod Value: "+PAYEEmployerDetail.payPeriodFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> PayFrequency Value: "+PAYEEmployerDetail.payFrequencyFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Salary/Wage Value: "+PAYEEmployerDetail.salaryWageFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Gross/Net Value "+"STATIC VALUE = GROSS");
//                      System.out.println("==> Employee Deduction Value "+PAYEEmployerDetail.employeeDeductionFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Employee Contribution Value "+PAYEEmployerDetail.employeeContributionFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> Child Support Deduction Value "+PAYEEmployerDetail.childSupportDeductionFinalValue);
//                      System.out.println("==> PayRoll Donation Value "+PAYEEmployerDetail.payrollDonationFinalValue);
//                      
                    }

                Thread.sleep(100);
                Log.i("ARRAY", ""+ m_orders.size());
            } catch (Exception e) { 
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }




 viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getOrders();
        }
    };

    thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(m_orders != null && m_orders.size() > 0){

                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                for(int i=0;i<m_orders.size();i++)
                    m_adapter.add(m_orders.get(i));
            }
           // m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
};
```

and the OrderAdapter is like:

```
private class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private ArrayList<Order> items;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Order> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.paye_list_row, null);
            }
            Order o = items.get(position);
            if (o != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value);

                    if (tt != null) {
                          tt.setText(o.getOrderName()); // Setting the Value here                            
                    }
                    if(bt != null){
                          bt.setText(o.getOrderStatus()); // Setting the Value here
                          System.out.println("The "+o.getOrderName()+" Value is: "+o.getOrderStatus());

                    }
            }
            return v;
    }
}
```

There is also one Order class where i am going to get and set the Value by getter setter method.

Now i want to implement such thing for multiple employee. Example: right now it is for one emplpoyee, and if uesr click on add button, then present all the value of orderStatus should be stored. and after that i should be able to add the another employee detail (data).

I also want to go to Next Employee, to previoue Employee and also delete that shown employee.

So how it is possible with the HashMap? or mY code is good enough to implement it ?
Please help me for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using only one employee object, you could use an `ArrayList<Employee>` and use that one.

As you modify data, you should think about when to save it. Possible would be to save every change, or just to save if you change the employee.

I would recommend to save the data in the database, so you can easily read and write them.

A small tip: You should refactor your `if (i==1) ...` to a switch/case for more maintainability.

Comment: Thanks. Please help me how to implement that for multiply employee. I mean all the data should be stored. as because i have to use of that data in Report. And i dont want to use DataBase at all. I know that it can be possible by the HashMap and ArrayList of that HashMap. But i got stuck to implement it in My code. So i need help for that.

Comment: Without a database, how do you want to store the data you have for your employees? How do you want to store the data between the app starts?

Comment: I dont want to store that data as like that. I just want it to be store at temporary lavel as like any variable can store. Just for calculation purpose.